# Import from folder next to this folder

Tags: python, import, include

I have the following folder structure:

```
/python
    /inc
        FILETOINCLUDE.py
    /currentProject
        main.py
```

neither /inc nor /python are set as project paths whatsoever (which might be the problem)

In main.py I tried the following (did some searching here, but without success)

```
from .. inc.FILETOINCLUDE import *
```

and

```
from ..inc.FILETOINCLUDE import *
```

and

```
from . inc.FILETOINCLUDE import *
```

...

Pretty much always resulting in: `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perfom relative import`

I'd like to use the `/inc` folder for all my following projects, which is why I'd like to keep it one level above the project. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If this is code that someone other than you might run, I strongly recommend putting `inc` in a known location, such as `/usr/lib/python/site-packages` instead. Otherwise, you can put it somewhere like `/home/me/python/inc`, and add the following to your shell resource file:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/me/python
```

Either way, you no longer need to use relative imports in your code, as the interpreter will know where to find the package `inc`.

Comment: can I make the PYTHONPATH relative? The thing with this solution is, that it won't work on windows and linux, and that it's not a drag&drop installation anymore.